# decreasing line spacing itemize latex

Tags: latex, spacing

I would like to place each item more close to each other, that is, decrease the line spacing but I didn't find any useful thing.

```
\begin{itemize}
         \item Processor: Intel Core \textsuperscript{TM} i5-5300U CPU @ 2.3GHz
         \item RAM: 8 GB
         \item OS: Windows 7
         \item Computer: HP840G
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in the preamble include `\usepackage{enumitem}` and then you can cutsom set the itemsep in the itemize like this: `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=20pt]` or no item seperator `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]`.